# Using Stockfish Chess AI in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, uci

Good Morning. I am trying to implement Stockfish to a Unity chess game, Ive been told that the best way is using Spawn.Process 
Does anyone know of existing code I can look at and take as reference?

Are different Gamestates the best way to communicate with AI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can represent your game state in [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) and read [Algebraic Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) to advance your board state, this should work:

```cs
string GetBestMove(string forsythEdwardsNotationString){
    var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "stockfishExecutable";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();  
    string setupString = "position fen "+forsythEdwardsNotationString;
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(setupString);
    
    // Process for 5 seconds
    string processString = "go movetime 5000";
    
    // Process 20 deep
    // string processString = "go depth 20";

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(processString);
    
    string bestMoveInAlgebraicNotation = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    p.Close();

    return bestMoveInAlgebraicNotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used http://chessforeva.blogspot.com/2010/10/unity3d-chess-project.html as a starting point for my MacOS, iOS, Android, Windows Chess App/Game a few years back.

It uses algebraic notation using FEN and the meat and potatoes of what you want to do are in c0_4unity_chess.js, and Scriptings.js. Also StockFishCall.js, under the Update() function you will see a similar to GetBestMove() function above, like Ruzihm mentioned using ProcessLineIN() for "bestmove".

In the c0_4unity_chess.js script, there are functions called c0_get_FEN(), c0_put_to_PGN(), and set_pos() which should help point you in the right direction.

Update: https://chessforeva.gitlab.io/
There's the gitlab.io link.

Comment: Thx but your link is dead, would it be possible for you to directly share the github link please?

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d3Uxa-k3vFidPSSCJaTxOkfEOadu5I0S/view is the source. Doesn't have a github.