# How to wait a task to end before to close the processus?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chess, uci

Recently i'm working on a chess and for the AI i'm using Stockfish with the UCI Protocol.
Thanks to this 2 following links ( UCI Protocol : http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html and this post : [Using Stockfish Chess AI in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852843/using-stockfish-chess-ai-in-unity) ) i have done some progress but i have an issue.

Here is my code :

```
        var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/stockfish/stockfish-11-win/Windows/stockfish_20011801_32bit";

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        p.Start();



        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("position fen " + fen);
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("go movetime 2000");
        myStreamWriter.Close();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);



        StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput;
        String bestMoveInAlgebraicNotation = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();


        p.Close();

        return bestMoveInAlgebraicNotation;
```

When i ask Stockfish an evaluation with this following code : `myStreamWriter.WriteLine("go movetime 2000");`

He does it but stop it right away when  i ask the processus to close : `p.Close();`

So i would like for the processus to wait until the task is done, is there anyway to do it and how?

Thansk for reading me and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

use `p.WaitForExit();`

[Sets the period of time to wait for the associated process to exit, and blocks the current thread of execution until the time has elapsed or the process has exited.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8)